# Corroboration of Weil anecdote

Tags: math-history

There is an anecdote at [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59773/can-i-go-through-hartshorne-without-knowing-much-analysis#comment138997_59840):

> There is an urban legend on Weil that supposedly happened when Weil, Halmos and Mac Lane were all professors in Chicago during the notorious Stone age. Weil was talking to some visitors in front of his office and said: We professors here are all good in some way: There are good mathematicians with bad taste (points down the hallway in direction of ML's office) bad mathematicians with good taste (same with H's office) and there are good mathematicians with good taste (no pointing).

Is this available in some printed source, possibly with more such anecdotes on the "Stone age"?